# How to use image stream in deploy configuration for OpenShift

Tags: openshift, kubernetes

I want my deploy configuration to use an image that was the output of a build configuration.

I am currently using something like this:

```
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: myapp
    name: myapp
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      app: myapp
      deploymentconfig: myapp
    strategy:
      resources: {}
    template:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          openshift.io/container.myapp.image.entrypoint: '["python3"]'
          openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          app: myapp
          deploymentconfig: myapp
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: 123.123.123.123/myproject/myapp-staging:latest
          resources: {}
          command:
            - scripts/start_server.sh
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
    test: false
    triggers: []
  status: {}
```

I had to hard-code the integrated docker registry's IP address; otherwise Kubernetes/OpenShift is not able to find the image to pull down.  I would like to not hard-code the integrated docker registry's IP address, and instead use something like this:

```
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: myapp
    name: myapp
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      app: myapp
      deploymentconfig: myapp
    strategy:
      resources: {}
    template:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          openshift.io/container.myapp.image.entrypoint: '["python3"]'
          openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          app: myapp
          deploymentconfig: myapp
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: myapp
          from:
            kind: "ImageStreamTag"
            name: "myapp-staging:latest"
          resources: {}
          command:
            - scripts/start_server.sh
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
    test: false
    triggers: []
  status: {}
```

But this causes Kubernetes/OpenShift to complain with:

```
The DeploymentConfig "myapp" is invalid.
spec.template.spec.containers[0].image: required value
```

How can I specify the output of a build configuration as the image to use in a deploy configuration?

Thank you for your time!

Also, oddly enough, if I link the deploy configuration to the build configuration with a trigger, Kubernetes/OpenShift knows to look in the integrated docker for the image:

```
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: myapp-staging
    name: myapp-staging
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      app: myapp-staging
      deploymentconfig: myapp-staging
    strategy:
      resources: {}
    template:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          openshift.io/container.myapp.image.entrypoint: '["python3"]'
          openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          app: myapp-staging
          deploymentconfig: myapp-staging
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: myapp-staging
          image: myapp-staging:latest
          resources: {}
          command:
            - scripts/start_server.sh
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
    test: false
    triggers:
    - type: "ImageChange"
      imageChangeParams:
        automatic: true
        containerNames:
        - myapp-staging
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: myapp-staging:latest
  status: {}
```

But I don't want the automated triggering...

Update 1 (11/21/2016):
Configuring the trigger but having the trigger disabled (hence manually triggering the deploy), still left the deployment unable to find the image:

```
$ oc describe pod myapp-1-oodr5
Name:                   myapp-1-oodr5
Namespace:              myproject
Security Policy:        restricted
Node:                   node.url/123.123.123.123
Start Time:             Mon, 21 Nov 2016 09:20:26 -1000
Labels:                 app=myapp
                        deployment=myapp-1
                        deploymentconfig=myapp
Status:                 Pending
IP:                     123.123.123.123
Controllers:            ReplicationController/myapp-1
Containers:
  myapp:
    Container ID:
    Image:              myapp-staging:latest
    Image ID:
    Port:               8000/TCP
    Command:
      scripts/start_server.sh
    State:              Waiting
      Reason:           ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:              False
    Restart Count:      0
    Volume Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-goe98 (ro)
    Environment Variables:
      ALLOWED_HOSTS:    myapp-myproject.url
Conditions:
  Type          Status
  Ready         False 
Volumes:
  default-token-goe98:
    Type:       Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-goe98
QoS Tier:       BestEffort
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                                    SubobjectPath                           Type            Reason          Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                                    -------------                           --------        ------          -------
  42s           42s             1       {scheduler }                                                                                    Scheduled       Successfully assigned myapp-1-oodr5 to node.url
  40s           40s             1       {kubelet node.url}  implicitly required container POD                       Pulled          Container image "openshift3/ose-pod:v3.1.1.7" already present on machine
  40s           40s             1       {kubelet node.url}  implicitly required container POD                       Created         Created with docker id d3318e880e4a
  40s           40s             1       {kubelet node.url}  implicitly required container POD                       Started         Started with docker id d3318e880e4a
  40s           24s             2       {kubelet node.url}  spec.containers{myapp}                            Pulling         pulling image "myapp-staging:latest"
  38s           23s             2       {kubelet node.url}  spec.containers{myapp}                            Failed          Failed to pull image "myapp-staging:latest": Error: image library/myapp-staging:latest not found
  35s           15s             2       {kubelet node.url}  spec.containers{myapp}                            Back-off        Back-off pulling image "myapp-staging:latest"
```

Update 2 (08/23/2017):
In case, this helps others, here's a summary of the solution.

```
triggers:    
- type: "ImageChange"
  imageChangeParams:
    automatic: true # this is required to link the build and deployment
    containerNames:
    - myapp-staging
    from:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: myapp-staging:latest
```

With the trigger and `automatic` set to `true`, the deployment should use the build's image in the internal registry.

The other comments relating to making the build not trigger a deploy relates to a separate requirement of wanting to manually deploy images from the internal registry.  Here's more information about that portion:

The build needs to trigger the deployment at least once before `automatic` is set to `false`.  So far a while, I was:

1. setting `automatic` to `true`
2. initiate a build and deploy
3. after deployment finishes, manually change `automatic` to `false`
4. manually, trigger a deployment later (though I did not verify if this deployed the older, out-of-date image or not)

I was initially trying to use this manual deployment as a way for a non-developer to go into the web console and make deployments.  But this requirement has since been removed, so having build trigger deployments each time works just fine for us now.  Builds can build at different branches and then tag the images differently.  Deployments can then just use the appropriately tagged images.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you constructing the resource definitions by hand?

It would be easier to use `oc new-build` and then `oc new-app` if you really need to set this up as two steps for some reason. If you just want to setup the build and deployment in one go, just use `oc new-app`.

For example, to setup build and deployment in one go use:

```
oc new-app --name myapp <repository-url>
```

To do it in two steps use:

```
oc new-build --name myapp <repository-url>
oc new-app myapp
```

If you still rather use hand created resources, at least use the single step variant with the `--dry-run -o yaml` options to see what it would create for the image stream, plus build and deployment configuration. That way you can learn from it how to do it. The bit you currently have missing is an image stream.

BTW. It looks a bit suspicious that you have the entry point set to `python3`. That is highly unusual. What are you trying to do as right now it looks like you may be trying to do something in a way which may not work with how OpenShift works. OpenShift is mainly about long running processes and not for doing single `docker run`. You can do the latter, but not how you are currently doing it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I initially did use `oc new-app` to output a template which I've built off of.  I do have a build config YAML that I didn't post.  But if you think it's important, I can post it.  I typically run `oc create -f ...` and have the build, image stream, deployment, service, and route all created and working.  I'm trying to make this modification to support a separate staging and production instance.  The staging instance works fine because the trigger somehow enables Openshift/Kubernetes to find the correct image.  I didn't want to have the production instance ...

Comment: ...automatically trigger.  So when I make a new deployment configuration without the trigger, OpenShift/Kubernetes can no longer find the image that was built from the build configuration since it looks to Docker Hub.

Comment: And the `python3` was leftover from the template created from `oc new-app`.  The `command` script seems to run the server okay even with the `entrypoint`.  Thanks again and please let me know if you see anything else suspicious!  :)

Comment: For the production deployment config, one way is to remove the ImageChange trigger from the deployment config thus meaning you have to always trigger deployment manually. An alternative is to rely on tagging of images to mark a migration from one environment to another. So don't rely on latest but a manually added tag. To move to production you update the tag to refer to the newer image. Finally, can use different projects. For the latter see https://blog.openshift.com/promoting-applications-across-environments/

Comment: Thanks again.  The trigger is what seems to be allowing the staging instance to pull the image correctly.  Removing the trigger is causing the production instance to fail when pulling the image.  Using the ip address in `image: 123.123.123.123/myproject/myapp-staging:latest` is allowing the production instance to pull the image correctly.  I just want a way to specify the image stream instead of hard coding the IP of the internal docker registry.  Is there a configuration to do that?  I'm not an admin of the infrastructure so giving users different admin rights across projects is...

Comment: ...something I want to avoid for now.  Thanks again!

Comment: Whoops, should not have said remove the ImageChange trigger, but disable it so requires manual triggering. Use the command ``oc set triggers --manual dc/myapp``. It should remove the ``automatic: true`` setting. It will remove the ConfigChange entry though. The ImageChange one is left, with its params so can still do manual deploy.

Comment: Ah I see, have the trigger configured so it knows where to look, but disable it with `automatic: false` so it won't trigger.  That seems round-about and hacky, but it'll get me through this.  I'll give that a try and post back.  Thanks again!

Comment: Hey @graham, sorry for the delay.  The cluster went down and other tasks came in.  But anyways, I tried linking the deploy to the image with a trigger, but disabling the trigger.  I guess if the trigger doesn't trigger, the deployment still cannot find the image.  Any other possible workarounds?  Thanks again for your time and have a Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: Not sure if this is your situation or not, but there is apparently a limitation that I learnt of since then that when the trigger is disabled, it will forever deploy the same image even if the image from the build is updated. You would have to reenable the trigger, trigger a new deployment, at which point it will update the image reference automatically, and then disable the trigger again.

Comment: Wow!  What a bunch of workarounds.  So yes, if I deploy, and then disable the trigger; everything is exactly as I want it (using the correct ImageStream image and manually triggered).  Now I don't know which is worst, hardcoding the IP of the internal Docker registry or doing this manual enable & disable for the initial deployment.  Either way, thank you so much for helping me sort through this.  Have a good one!

Comment: It is a known issue that has been talked about and there are possibly changes coming related to it, but am not sure.

Comment: this is the same problem I'm facing. It looks more like a bug than a feature. Also it does not seems possible to define triggers on stateful pods (openshift 1.5 alpha 2) which makes the work around not feasibles.

Comment: Could you please post the resulting yaml/json?

Comment: @JiriKremser, I've updated the question with a summary of the answer.  The YAML needs looks the same as the one previously posted, so I just highlighted the important section.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I just want to put a comment for this. Disable ImageChange trigger works for me. After building container image, `oc rollout latest` command bring the latest container image and deploy it as a Pod.